# FPS decreasing while rendering a CSS3 animation

Tags: html, css

We have a web page in which we are trying to show a side-bar.

This one should push the page increasing its right margin, as show in [this example](http://leakedbits.com/example/).

As you can see if you open the side-bar while the slide image hasn't changed it's more fluid than doing it when new images have appeared.

Our problem is caused by the slideshow, as we start with just one animation but, after a delay new animations are been launching, going to six (three slides and three text divs), and this makes the side-bar to be less fluid.

Is there any possible solution to prevent this happening or make the animations and transitions more fluid? If possible I'd like not using javascript.

Comment: The more "animations" you have on a page, the lower the FPS will be as it taxes the browser. Also, I think JS animations can be better for this.

Comment: No, the issue is the images resizing. If you take out your slideshow, the transition looks fine. But when you force multiple huge images to resize all at once, it's going to look choppy. I'd look into keeping them the same size rather than 100%.